# How to add border to text in a button?

Tags: swift, text, uibutton, border

I have a button with some text and i need to add border to this is text 0.2 px, i used @IBDesignable but it work for button not for text.

my code:

```
@IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 1.0{
        didSet{
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderTextColor:UIColor?{
        didSet{
            layer.borderColor = borderTextColor?.cgColor
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add the screenshot of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a border to the text itself you can use an attributed string to add a stroke to the text. You can do this for most text related UI elements within `UIKit` such as a `UILabel` or `UIButton`

```
// Create the stroke attributes
let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.strokeColor: UIColor.black,
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
    NSAttributedString.Key.strokeWidth: -4.0
];

// Create the text with a stroke as an attributed string
let textWithStroke = NSAttributedString(
    string: "Button Text",
    attributes: attributes
);

// Set the attributed string to the button
button.setAttributedTitle(textWithStroke, for: .normal);
```

Use a negative value for the `.strokeWidth` so the stroke outlines the outside of the text and not the inside

If you want to edit the font just add the `NSAttributedString.Key.font` key with a value of `UIFont` to the `attributes` array

Answer (score 0):

You can simply give the button a ID & just use normal CSS Like this-

```
#myButton{text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;}
```

This will just create a shadow like outline to your text. Manage the colors according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding border to your `UIButton` not `UILabel`. Use `UILabel` for text not `UIButton` text and then assign border to `UILabel` like this

```
    yourLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    yourLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2
    yourLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
```

Comment: Hi! i knew how it work for label but i need modify text for button not for label.) Thanks! Maybe you know way for modify text inside the button?

Comment: Can you show me the design? what exactly you want ?

Comment: @AwaisKhan The code you gave will add `border` to the `label's frame` and not to the `text` inside it.

Comment: I have button and inside this is button has text "hello" and I need add border for this is text not for Button.

Comment: I think it is not possible . You want to add border to the text placed inside UILabel and that text has a data type of String. So it is not possible to give border to String.